# Is there a version of Live Writer for Windows Phone?

Tags: apps

Has Microsoft made, or will they be making a version of [Live Writer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-live/essentials-other-programs?T1=t5) for the Windows Phone? Maybe for Windows Phone 8?

Live Writer is a wonderful app I use on my desktop computer to update my WordPress blog posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Wordpress, you can use their official app for managing your blog. Just search for "wordpress" in marketplace or follow this [link](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=5f64ad85-f801-e011-9264-00237de2db9e).

I think there is no mobile version of Live Writer.

Comment: I did try that app, and unfortunately it requires Wordpress 2.9.2 or later, and I am unable to upgrade from 2.7.x. See: http://wpwindowsphone.wordpress.com/faq/#faq_1

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Windows live stuff (msn, windows live mail, ...) seem to have no future with Microsoft, so they may not develop an app for windowsphone as you are looking for.

Comment: I understand that is all speculation. Microsoft has not released its plans and may in fact currently working on converting their Windows Live apps to Windows 8 and create apps for them like they did with SkyDrive. Do you have a link or a news report with something said by Microsoft to confirm your statement that "Windows live stuff ... have no future with Microsoft?"